# Display a variable from SQL in php file PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have two lines of code I need help with. Been at it forever total newbie with SQL stuff here

I need to add a domain url field
I have managed to add the new column to the SQL
I have managed to add the new field to a form to insert into SQL
The form successfuly changes data in SQL etc. I have researched how to add the data from sql to the php but every example i try breaks the process

in the lines below i need to change the hardcoded value -> demo.domain.com/ <-
the column name I added to SQL is domain_url

```
    $objWriter->save(str_replace(__FILE__,'demo.domain.com/exported-files/demo-orders-from'.str_replace('/','-',$queue_from_date).'-to'.str_replace('/','-',$queue_to_date).'-'.$queue_id.'.xls',__FILE__));
        
        
        $mail->addAttachment('demo.domain.com/exported-files/demo-orders-from'.str_replace('/','-',$queue_from_date).'-to'.str_replace('/','-',$queue_to_date).'-'.$queue_id.'.xls');
```

Then I also Have this

```
                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('Y'.$rowCount, '1 Goodrich Ave');
                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('Z'.$rowCount, 'Sarasota');
                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('AA'.$rowCount, 'FL');
                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('AB'.$rowCount, '34236');
                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('AC'.$rowCount, 'US');
```

and i need to replace with data from the SQL

app_address
app_city
app_state
app_zipcode
app_country